# How to use an array to render dynamically multiple templates in Meteor?

Tags: javascript, meteor, meteor-blaze, spacebars, meteor-helper

I am having problems with rendering templates using the data from the helper.

```
Template.bonus.helpers({
    Userform: function(){
      return UserForms.find({owner:Meteor.userId()});
    },
    warehouse: function(){
      return Warehouse.find({});
    },
    DisplayForm: [
      { formname: "SW - Picking" },
      { formname: "SW - Packing" },
      { formname: "SW - Putaway" }
    ]
  });
```

Basically I just want to achieve something like this:

```
<div id="placeholder" class="col-md-8">
    {{#each DisplayForm}}
        {{> {{formname}} }}       //Render 3 templates "SW - Picking","SW - ....
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

I am sure it is fairly easy but I just need the correct syntax so I can use data from helper as a name of a template to be rendered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can include a template dynamically in Meteor by using **[`{{> Template.dynamic template=template [data=data] }}`](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/template_dynamic)**.

For example:

```
<body>
  {{> bonus}}
</body>

<template name="bonus">
  {{#each displayForm}}
    {{> Template.dynamic template=formname }}
    <br />
  {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="picking">
  Picking Template
</template>

<template name="packing">
  Packing Template
</template>

<template name="putaway">
  Putaway Template
</template>
```

---

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {
  Template.bonus.helpers({
    displayForm: [{
      formname: "picking"
    }, {
      formname: "packing"
    }, {
      formname: "putaway"
    }]
  });
}
```

Here is a [MeteorPad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/hdXPJPt6NRqmY33BR/Dynamic-templates-in-Meteor).